# What is the motivation for defining $f(x)=e^x$ as " the unique function EXP differentiable on R such that EXP'$(x)=$EXP$(x)$ and EXP$(0)=1$ "?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

In some french books, I can find the above definition of the exponential function with base $e$.

This defnition does not seem to be so common in books written in English.

What is the point of defining the $e^x$ function as

"the unique function "$\operatorname{EXP}$" differentiable on $\Bbb R$ such that $\operatorname{EXP}'(x)=\operatorname{EXP}(x)$ and $\operatorname{EXP}(0)=1$"?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the definition? What other definitions have you seen and how do they compare?

Comment: It is the way it is defined in Spivak's *Calculus*.

Comment: @Bernard No, it is not. Spivak defines $\exp$ as $\log^{-1}$; see chapter 18.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I mentioned it from memory, and I couldn't check, as I don't have the book  at home. So I guess that either it is in an exercise or some appendix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you accept that there is such a function, its basic properties are easy to prove from such a definition. For instance, suppose that you want to prove that$$(\forall x,y\in\Bbb R):\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y).$$Take $y\in\Bbb R$ and define$$\eta(x)=\frac{\exp(x+y)}{\exp(y)}.$$Then $\eta'=\eta$ and $\eta(0)=1$. So $\eta=\exp$ and therefore, if $x\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}\exp(x+y)&=\eta(x)\exp(y)\\&=\exp(x)\exp(y).\end{align}It follows from this that you never have $\exp(x)=0$ and therefore, since $\exp(0)=1>0$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $\exp(x)$ is always greater than $0$. But then, since $\exp'=\exp$, $\exp$ is strictly increasing; in particular, it is injective. So, it has an inverse, and we have\begin{align}\left(\exp^{-1}\right)'(x)&=\frac1{\exp'\left(\exp^{-1}(x)\right)}\\&=\frac1{\exp\left(\exp^{-1}(x)\right)}\\&=\frac1x.\end{align}And so on…

Comment: Thanks Mr Santos !

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.